# Converting a bitmap into a view

Tags: android

I have a bitmap that I want to use translate animation on it. since I can't do it on a bitmap I would like to convert it to a view so I could animate it.
how do I do it?

Comment: Why don't you animate the imageView which contains the bitmap?

Comment: I draw the bitmap on a canvas using drawBitmap method.

Comment: Then animate the canvas

Comment: But I dont want the whole canvas to move. What I have is a bitmap in the center, and onTouch I want to move it to the location that was touched.

Comment: Well the `ImageView` is a `View`. But using canvas means doing some redrawing.

Comment: 'sprite.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.knightleft));' thats how I set my bitmap and then I do my animation on sprite, and sprite is a bitmap

Comment: BTW you cannot use translate animation on Canvas, its your own code to develop your own traslation redrawing. Also it is not ideal to use ImageView if there is a reason why you need to use Canvas.

Comment: So how do I move a bitmap from a coordinate to a coordinate? I tried to increase x value and y value of the bitmap using invalidate, but I want the animation to be at the same speed wherever I press